# Is there any way I can make it so I don't have to redeclare dependencies for module.exports?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, node-modules

I am working on a discord bot. I'm kinda a new at this, so I followed discordjs.guide for this bot. I was wondering if there was a way I could use module.exports, while not having to constantly redeclare dependencies such as `const Discord = require('discord.js')` or function that I have in app.js.

Repo here:
https://github.com/boomermath/grapeoverhaul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `app.js` file, whatever parameters you pass into `execute()` will passover to the command file. So just add `Discord` into the parameters.

```
command.execute(Discord, message, args);
```

**Make sure the order of parameters is the exact same across all files, otherwise this will cause an error**

Comment: Additional question: If I had multiple dependencies, like xyz abc etc. Is there a way I could group them so I could pass all dependencies as command.execute(dependcies, message, args)?