# Based of previous question for discord.js dependency

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

[Is there any way I can make it so I don't have to redeclare dependencies for module.exports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64430812/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-it-so-i-dont-have-to-redeclare-dependencies-for-mod/64430908?noredirect=1#comment113931293_64430908)
(Previous Post)

Adding on to that, could I group dependencies, e.g. xyz, abc, and discord.js, and pass it as

`command.execute(dependencies, message, args)`

Where dependencies is all the dependencies I need for my bot, or do I have to pass each dependency seperately.

Github: https://github.com/boomermath/grapeoverhaul

Comment: You could put all the dependencies into an object, pass that object and then use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get all the dependencies separatly in your command files

Comment: I was thinkin about something along those lines. I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can group your dependencies by putting them in an object. E.G.:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config  = require('./config.json');
let dependencies = {
  "fs": fs,
  "Discord": Discord,
  "config": config,
}
```

Then, you pass dependencies in your function.
Next, if your other file you have is something like:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'bal',
    aliases: ['balance', 'wallet'],
    description: 'check ur balance',
    execute(message, args, dependencies ) {
        ...code 
    //say you need discord here 
    dependencies.Discord.somefunc()
    //say you need fs here
    dependencies.fs.writefile() // or something else
   }
```

You can with also rename your dependencies if you think their named wrong just change the part that is in quotes in your dependencies object!

Comment: @boomermath happy to help